# how to split data into train and test based on a column values and shuffle the combinations?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataset where I want to split the data set based on the column values. At every iteration, the training set will include all data except those that belong to 2 values which will be kept for test set.

As an example, we have column `x` with values `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f`.

At the moment I am doing a manual selection but since I want to try it for every possible combinations, I am not sure how best to do that.

```
train = df.loc[~df['x'].isin(['a','b'])]
test = df.loc[df['x'].isin(['a','b'])]
```

How do I change this code to consider all possible combinations?

I would also like to be able to print these combinations to see the combinations that were used for training and test sets.

Comment: Do you want to split the data in test and train, or find all the possible combinations of test and train?

Comment: its to find all possible combinations of test and train with the test set having data belonging to 2 values of x in every iteration. i will try the suggestions provided below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested, but how about using [`itertools.combinations`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/464882/2573061) like:

```
for holdouts in itertools.combinations(df['x'].unique(), 2):
    print(holdouts)
    train = df[~df['x'].isin(holdouts)]
    test = df[df['x'].isin(holdouts)]
```

You could save an evaluation by doing `mask = df['x'].isin(holdouts)`

Note that `.loc` isn't necessary for indexing on a boolean

Answer (score 0):

iteratetools.combinations should work.

Comment: It's `itertools` not `iteratetools` and my answer already says that.